# How do I import a disk image into libvirt?

Tags: virtualization, chmod

Can someone post the proper syntax? I have tried using the chmod command , but I am doing something incorrectly. I am just trying to move a centos iso file to /images to set up a test vm

Comment: Can you post the commands you're trying to run? And what's the error message?

Answer (score 17):

You're not really "supposed" to do it that way, since libvirt takes care of its own volume pools. Use:

```
size=$(stat -Lc%s centos.iso)
virsh vol-create-as default centos $size --format raw
virsh vol-upload --pool default centos centos.iso
```

This will create a virsh volume called `centos` in the default pool with the contents of `centos.iso`.

This way, libvirt takes care of all the required permissions and ownership itself.

Comment: First time I've used the forum . Excellent advice.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old post but I wanted to share what I did.

In my case, I needed to import a qcow2 image into a volume. I've used jq, qemu-img and and bash:

```
# export IMGSIZE=$(qemu-img info --output json /data/myfile.qcow2 | jq -r .[\"virtual-size\"])
# export IMGFMT=$(qemu-img info --output json /data/myfile.qcow2 | jq -r .format)
```

List the pools and select the one you want:

```
# virsh pool-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart
-------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes

# export IMGPOOL=default
```

Create the volume:

```
# virsh vol-create-as $IMGPOOL myvolume $IMGSIZE --format $IMGFMT
Vol myvolume created
```

And upload the image:

```
# virsh vol-upload --pool $IMGPOOL myvolume /data/myfile.qcow2
```

I don't know if you can pipe qemu-img to virsh, sort of like 'qemu-img dd ... | virsh vol-upload ...'  but that would be convenient :-)

Thanks @Robie Basak for his post,  I've used it to write the information above.

Answer (score 2):

I assume two things: `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` is owned by `root` and you are not `root`. That's fine but you have to respect that's what the problem is.

It would probably make most sense to just copy the file over *as root*, using `sudo`:

```
sudo cp my-image /var/lib/libvirt/images/
```

Alternatively, you can take over `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`:

```
sudo chown $USER /var/lib/libvirt/images/
```

Or (least good) you could just make it globally writable:

```
sudo chmod 755 $USER /var/lib/libvirt/images/
```

I'd follow the logic that it's root for a reason but if you're just playing around and this is never going to be a production machine, you probably don't need to be that careful.

Comment: I probably go with the last command as I understand this one and it is a test environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it in nautilus
just type

```
sudo -i nautilus
```

and after that copy the file as you would normally do.

Comment: Do I assume that nautilus is loaded?

Comment: nautilus is the default file manager for Ubuntu. I don't think i really understand your question.

Comment: @Rat2000 [FYI](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6634/psa-gksu-is-no-longer-installed-by-default)

Comment: Oli yes, you are right gksudo is not instaled by default, so i changed the command to sudo -i, that should do the job.